# WMS to processable raster

Tags: raster, geoprocessing

I´m using a layer from this WMS (https://www.fao.org/giews/earthobservation/show_gis_layer.jsp?code=ETH&img_id=HiH_VHt). I can´t make geoprocesses or any other action (I want to clip by a certain mask). An error occurs saying

> The file does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name

So I tried to first export as .tif to process it after. However, when exporting one has to set the resolution manually (I don't know the exact resolution of the input), it is supposed to be just like the input. Also the symbology has changed from singleband color data to multiband. I just want to have the WMS as a processable .tif. Does anyone have a solution to that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It would help to [Edit] the Question to specify the *exact* procedure that generates the error.

Comment: A wms is a picture of the data, you need to find a wcs to download raster data

Comment: The link you give isn't to a WMS the link is to a web map.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "About this data", scroll down and find the Data URL and copy the [WCS link](https://io.apps.fao.org/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=1.1.1&request=DescribeCoverage&identifiers=ASIS:vhi_d)

[image]